# Python/Excel/SQL column dates to exploded rows

Tags: python, sql, excel, pandas

I have an Excel spreadsheet table like this where it shows how many units were sold each week for 2019 and 2020 (columns) and I am trying to put it into an access database formatted like the second table:

```
| model | 2019 - Wk 1 U's | 2019 - Wk 2 U's | 2019 - Wk 3 U's | ... | 2020 - Wk 52 U's |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 abc            50                45                65                    20
 def            72                93                57                    68
```

and I want to get it like this

```
| model | year | month | week | units | 
---------------------------------------
 abc      2019    1       1      50
 abc      2019    1       2      45
 abc      2019    1       3      65
 def      2019    1       5      72
 def      2019    1       6      93
 def      2019    1       7      57
 ...      ....    ..      ..     .. 
 abc      2020    12      52     20
 def      2020    12      52     68
```

What's the best way to do this in Python (pandas) or VBA/Excel formula (or SQL if need be)?

Comment: How big is the table? And does the 1st table contain months?

Comment: @xlsx 1st table does not show months unfortunately, but I can add this on manually after. Table has 800 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to be systematic

1. row index `set_index("model")`
2. name column series `df.columns.set_names("weekencoded", inplace=True)`
3. then you are ready to `stack()`
4. rename column to *units*, `reset_index()` so encoded string is available as columns
5. parse out the values you want from encoded string
6. I've left it for you to convert a *week number* to a *month number*

```
data = """| model | 2019 - Wk 1 U's | 2019 - Wk 2 U's | 2019 - Wk 3 U's | ... | 2020 - Wk 52 U's |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 abc            50                45                65                    20
 def            72                93                57                    68"""

df = pd.DataFrame([[c for c in l.split(" ") if c!=""] for l in data.split("\n")[2:]],
            columns=[c.strip() for c in data.split("\n")[0].split("|") if c!="" and "..." not in c])

df.set_index("model", inplace=True)
df.columns.set_names("weekencoded", inplace=True)
df = df.stack().to_frame().rename(columns={0:"units"}).reset_index().assign(
    year=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda s: re.match("20[1,2][0-9]", s["weekencoded"])[0], axis=1),
    week=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda s: re.findall(r"(^.*Wk )([0-9]+)( U.*$)", s["weekencoded"])[0][1], axis=1),
)
```

**output**

```
model       weekencoded units  year week
  abc   2019 - Wk 1 U's    50  2019    1
  abc   2019 - Wk 2 U's    45  2019    2
  abc   2019 - Wk 3 U's    65  2019    3
  abc  2020 - Wk 52 U's    20  2020   52
  def   2019 - Wk 1 U's    72  2019    1
  def   2019 - Wk 2 U's    93  2019    2
  def   2019 - Wk 3 U's    57  2019    3
  def  2020 - Wk 52 U's    68  2020   52
```

Comment: Brilliant. Would never have been able to get this by myself.

Comment: Is there a way that I can reverse it too to get it back to how it was before?